# I have a state electric hot water heater and everything is working but still no hot water

Tags: electrical, water-heater

i have a state electric hot water heater ,30 years old but have always just replaced elements , so when the element went bad this time we replaced it and it worked for one whole day and then it quit heating water but the element is working but no hot water so the we replaced the thermostat and still nothing, what do we do now?

Comment: If element is working and there is water in the tank, then must have hot water.  Is the water not hot enough or no water coming out of the tank?

Comment: How do you know the element is working?  There would need to be water to absorb the heat and current draw to produce heat.  If it’s working and the thermostat is functional you would have hot water.

Comment: You say that "everything is working", but the evidence suggests otherwise. Test the elements and the thermostat - doesn't matter that they're "new",

Comment: I will take a SWAG and say it is the dip tube on the cold water inlet. If this is correct you will get some warm water for a short time then it will go cold. There should be two elements in the tank, be sure both are OK>

Comment: THANK YOU  ALL  FOR TRYING TO HELP ME, IM JUST SAYING THAT I HAVE PUT FOUR NEW ELEMENTS IN NO LESS THEN A WEEK CAUSE I WAS BEING TOLD THAT IT COULD BE THE ELEMENTS EVEN THOUGH THEY ARE NEW, SO THATS WHY I CHANGED THEM SO MANY TIMES AND THEN BOUT NEW THERMOSTAT AFTER I PUT LAST ELEMENT IN THINKING THATS WHAT IT WAS, NOW I REPLACED MY BREAKER ALSO, AND THE THERMOSTAT IS SET ON 130 AND THE WATER HAS GOTTEN WARMER BUT ITS NOT HOT SO NOW WHAT IF ANYTHING I CAN DO NOW. THANKS